# retryWhen only fires once, not multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using NGRX in an angular project to keep track of upload state for a bunch of files.

I want to limit the number of active uploads to 3. I have an effect that responds to an action whenever a new file is added to the queue. In the effect, I want to determine whether this file can start uploading.

Here's my effect:

```js
canStartUpload$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ImageActions.updateImageWithFullUpload),
        withLatestFrom(this._store.select(selectActiveUploadsTotal)), // gets active uploads from state
        mergeMap((values) => {
            return iif(
                () => values[1] < 3, // conditionally checks if the current upload 
                this.tis.getImageUploadS3Link(values[0].image._id)
                    .pipe(map(({url}) => ImageActions.uploadImage({image: values[0].image, url }))), // Starts upload
                throwError(new Error('Cannot upload at the moment'))// throws errors to be caught by 'retryWhen' method. 
            )

        }),
        retryWhen(errors => {
           return errors.pipe(
               tap(err => console.log(err)),// This only logs once, not multiple times
               tap(() => console.log("Retrying Upload")),
               delay(10000),
               take(10)
           )
        })

    )
)
```

**The problem is, the source observable is not retried multiple times. It logs "Retrying Upload" once and then never again even though the conditional check still says it should retry again.**

**My guess is that when an error is thrown on the outer stream, then the stream dies, instead of being retried.**

If that's the case, how can I create an inner stream that retries multiple times while also getting the most recent state from the state machine and pass that value to the [`iif` function.](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif)

In an effort to explain exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, here is some pseudo code:

Start processing effect when action fires

---

Get active uploads from state machine

Check if condition is met( less than 3 active uploads)

If true --> start upload

If false --> retry in 10 seconds(starting with getting state from state machine)

---

Try this block maximum of 10 times.

Comment: Try moving the `retryWhen` block right after the `throwError` inside of the `mergeMap`.

Comment: @AliF50 If I do that, then it does retry successfully, but it does not retry with the updated state from the state machine. It retries with the old state which means that more files are uploaded than desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to use the `useEffectsErrorHandler` [config property](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/models.ts#L4):

```js
createEffect(
  () => /* ... */,
  { useEffectsErrorHandler: true }
);
```

By using the above option, the [`defaultEffectsErrorHandler` function](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/effects/src/effects_error_handler.ts#L13) will make sure that if the effects stream does not catch an error, it will be resubscribed. By default, there is a maximum of 10 attempts:

```js
export function defaultEffectsErrorHandler<T extends Action>(
  observable$: Observable<T>,
  errorHandler: ErrorHandler,
  retryAttemptLeft: number = MAX_NUMBER_OF_RETRY_ATTEMPTS
): Observable<T> {
  return observable$.pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      if (errorHandler) errorHandler.handleError(error);
      if (retryAttemptLeft <= 1) {
        return observable$; // last attempt
      }
      // Return observable that produces this particular effect
      return defaultEffectsErrorHandler(
        observable$,
        errorHandler,
        retryAttemptLeft - 1
      );
    })
  );
}
```

You can provide your own *effects-error-handler* function:

```js
{
  provide: EFFECTS_ERROR_HANDLER,
  useValue: yourCustomHandler,
},
```

---

Another way to solve this, which does not involve setting any other options, would be to adjust the effect a bit:

```js
canStartUpload$ = createEffect(() => 
  this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ImageActions.updateImageWithFullUpload),
  
  mergeMap(
    action => timer(0, 10_000).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this._store.select(selectActiveUploadsTotal)), // gets active uploads from state,
      filter([, activeUploadsTotal] => activeUploadsTotal < 3),
      mapTo(action),

      // stop the timer when the condition is true
      // otherwise, let the timer be active and keep checking
      take(1),
    )
  ),

  mergeMap(
    action => this.tis.getImageUploadS3Link(values[0].image._id).pipe(
      map(({url}) => ImageActions.uploadImage({image: values[0].image, url }))
    )
  ),
)
```

Comment: +1 for adding in the config option. Although, I liked your second solution better  and ended up going with a similar solution, I appreciate you including the config option. I had no idea you could provide your own custom error handler. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.) Have one effect stream concerned about the successful action emission of uploadImage or cant upload image.

2.) Have a listener for the action of can't upload image in an effect and do what you would like (delay of 10s, take(10)) and then resend that action.

Something I am iffy on is the `take(10)` where now the `take(10)` has become global. Meaning that if the user uploads one file and they retry 5 times and then they try uploading again and retry 5 times and then 3rd time they are out of retries. I think that `take(10)` should refresh somehow, someway.

```
canStartUpload$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ImageActions.updateImageWithFullUpload),
        withLatestFrom(this._store.select(selectActiveUploadsTotal)), // gets active uploads from state
        mergeMap((values) => {
            return iif(
                () => values[1] < 3, // conditionally checks if the current upload 
                this.tis.getImageUploadS3Link(values[0].image._id)
                    .pipe(map(({url}) => ImageActions.uploadImage({image: values[0].image, url }))), // Starts upload
                map(_ => ImageActions.cantUploadAtTheMoment()), // create this action
            )
        }),
    )
)

cantUploadAtTheMoment$ = createEffect(() => {
   this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(ImageActions.cantUploadAtTheMoment),
     delay(10000),
     take(10),
     map(_ => ImageActions.updateImageWithFullUpload) // recall the action that will start the canStartUpload$ stream.
   )
});
```